# How to Ajaxify a Partial View which uses Razor Validation

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I'm very new to MVC Razor (as is our entire team)
My question is How to Ajaxify a Partial view, but only if the Razor HtmlValidationMessagefor has checked what it should, then the ajax call.

The beneath code allows the ajax call even if nothing was selected from the DDL (which has a validation attribute.),
and do it again and there is a failure..it loses it's model.

Totally lost we are.

**Parent** 
***Host.cshtml***

```html
@model ReloadPartials.Models.MyContainer
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Host";
}

<div class="form-horizontal" id="divHost">
 <h2>Host</h2>
 
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Host", "Example"))
 {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.Partial("Header", Model)
  @Html.Partial("Details", Model)

  <div id="divFooter" />
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" name="actionPerformed" value="Save All" class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-2 col-md-2" />
  </div>
 }
</div>
@section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Details cshtml**

```html
@model ReloadPartials.Models.MyContainer

@{
 ViewBag.DetailIndex = 0;
 int detailItemsSideBySide = 2;
 int currentDetailItem = 1;
 int i = 0;
}
<div class="form-horizontal" id="divDetails">
 <h2>Details Section</h2>
  @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count(); i++)
  {*@
   Model.Details[i].Index = i;
   ViewBag.DetailIndex = i;

   <div id="@("divDetails_"+i)">
    @Html.Partial("Detail", Model)
   </div>

   if (currentDetailItem == detailItemsSideBySide)
   {
    currentDetailItem = 0;
    <div id="divFooter" />
   }
   currentDetailItem++;
  @*}*@
</div>
```

***Detail.cshtml
(The inner single (or multiple instances of this partial view, depending on Details.cshtml)***

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
  $("#btnReload" + @ViewBag.DetailIndex).on("click", function ()
  {
   alert("ajax ... " + @ViewBag.DetailIndex);

   var val = $('#txtInput'+@ViewBag.DetailIndex).val();
   var ModelData =  $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
     url: "/Example/GetAjaxPostBackData_OnlyTextBox",
     type: "GET",
     data: { ajaxDetailModelData: ModelData, index: @ViewBag.DetailIndex}
     ,
     async: false
     //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     //dataType: "json"
     })
     .done(function (partialViewResult)
     {
      alert("ajax done " + @ViewBag.DetailIndex);
      //This replaces the Partial in the Div, with the new partial
      $('#divDetails_' +@ViewBag.DetailIndex).replaceWith(partialViewResult);
     });
   });
  });

</script>
```

```html
@model ReloadPartials.Models.MyContainer

@{
 int index = ViewBag.DetailIndex;
}

<div class="form-horizontal" id="divDetail">
 <h2>Detail Section @index.ToString()</h2>

 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Details[index].HeaderId)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Details[index].Id)

 <div class="form-group" id="ddlDiv">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Details[index].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">

   @*This on change will call submit*@
   @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Details[index].Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.Names, "Select a Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })*@

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Details[index].Name,
    (SelectList)ViewBag.Names, "Select a Name",
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , id = "ddlNames" + index.ToString() })

   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details[index].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="txtInpDiv">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Details[index].SomeNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details[index].SomeNumber,
     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtInput" + index.ToString() } })
   
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details[index].SomeNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   <p>@Model.Details[index].SomeNumber.ToString()</p>

  </div>

  <div id="BottomDiv"></div>
 </div>

 @*This button (and/or combo onchange) should actually go get data from the server and then just reload this detail section using AJAX*@
 @*Use razor and the viewbag to uniquely identify each instance of this partial, such that we can identify which instance of this partial invoked the Ajax call*@
 <div class="form-group">
  <button id ="@("btnReload" +  @ViewBag.DetailIndex)" name="actionPerformed" value="Reload Detail"
    class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">Reload</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

**The controller**

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    private MyContainer InitialiseContainer()
    {
        MyContainer containter = new MyContainer();

        containter.Header = new MyHeader(1, "Header Name");
        containter.Details.Add(new MyDetail(1, 1, "Detail 1 Name", 100));
        containter.Details.Add(new MyDetail(1, 2, "Detail 2 Name", 200));

        return containter;
    }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Host()
{
    //ViewBag.xxSelectedItem = "Detail Name 4";
    Session["isAjaxCall"] = false;
    MyContainer container = InitialiseContainer();
    ViewBag.Names = NamesLookup(null);
    return View(container);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Host(MyContainer container, string actionPerformed)
{
    if (actionPerformed == "Save All")
    {
        //return RedirectToAction("xxx");
    }
    if (actionPerformed == "Reload Detail") 
    {
        if ((bool)Session["isAjaxCall"] == true)
        {
            ViewBag.DetailIndex = 0;
            ViewBag.Names = NamesLookup(null);
            NewModelContainer = (MyContainer)Session["MyContainer"];
            return PartialView("Detail", NewModelContainer);
        }
        else
        {
            //this action runs if , from the ajax code we reference the Div(s) set by the parent view "Details"
            container = setsomeValues(container);
            ViewBag.DetailIndex = 0;
            ViewBag.Names = NamesLookup(null);
            return View(container);
        }
    }

    ViewBag.Names = NamesLookup(null);
    return View(container);
}


`public PartialViewResult GetAjaxPostBackData_OnlyTextBox(string ajaxDetailModelData, string index)
{

    Session["isAjaxCall"] = true;

    int i = 0;
    int.TryParse(index, out i);
    ViewBag.DetailIndex = i;

    //get the items to populate the dropdown List with
    ViewBag.Names = NamesLookup(null);

    //get an instance of the Model (Container), either from session (with changed and persisted values in it, or Cleanly re-initialized)
    MyContainer NewModelContainer = InitialiseContainer();
    NewModelContainer = UnpackAjaxdetailModelData(ajaxDetailModelData,index); 

    //arb Test ..change the HTML Input 
    NewModelContainer.Details[i].SomeNumber = 777;

    Session["NewModelContainer"] = NewModelContainer;

    //return just the partial view as indexed, which's btnXXX_index was clicked
    return PartialView("Detail", NewModelContainer);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
private SelectList NamesLookup(object selectedObject)
{
    List<MyName> names = new List<MyName>();

    names.Add(new MyName(1, "Detail Name 1"));
    names.Add(new MyName(2, "Detail Name 2"));
    names.Add(new MyName(3, "Detail Name 3"));
    names.Add(new MyName(4, "Detail Name 4"));
    names.Add(new MyName(5, "Detail Name 5"));

    return new SelectList(names, "Name", "Name", selectedObject);
}

}
```

thanks

Layout

Comment: You handle the forms `.submit()` event and check the `.valid()` method (and if `false`, then cancel the ajax call) - `$('form').submit(function() { if (!$(this).valid() { return; } / make ajax call });`

Comment: Ok thx, but /i have no idea how to do that.
Is this all from within the ajax click event? 
Is this what is causing it to lose it's model on the second Reload click?

Comment: Googling forms .submit() event results in not MVC but webforms stuff

Comment: So,..as a test, I remove the Validations.
Click reload once..works.
Click reload again and it crashes with
(after going thru the ajax handler  AND then .  Goes thru Host Action
..and crashes with …the Model referenced beneath 

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Why would it go thru the Host action as well with the second click on Reload?

Comment: Solution:
The button type had to be specified as type='button'   and
the inner partial's outer div needed indexing as such:
 id="divDetail" + @index.ToString()